# Python: get list indexes using regular expression?

Tags: python

In Python, how do you get the position of an item in a list (using `list.index`) using fuzzy matching?

For example, how do I get the indexes of all fruit of the form `*berry` in the following list?

```
fruit_list = ['raspberry', 'apple', 'strawberry']
# Is it possible to do something like the following?
berry_fruit_at_positions = fruit_list.index('*berry')
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That's not a regular expression.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't fuzzy, either.  Just the opposite, actually: they're very strict and precise.

Comment: That's not a regex

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try:

```
fruit_list = ['raspberry', 'apple', 'strawberry']
[ i for i, word in enumerate(fruit_list) if word.endswith('berry') ]
```

returns:

```
[0, 2]
```

Replace `endswith` with a different logic according to your matching needs.

Answer (score 71):

With regular expressions:

```
import re
fruit_list = ['raspberry', 'apple', 'strawberry']
berry_idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(fruit_list) if re.search('berry$', item)]
```

And without regular expressions:

```
fruit_list = ['raspberry', 'apple', 'strawberry']
berry_idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(fruit_list) if item.endswith('berry')]
```

Comment: This answer should have been selected as the answer.

Comment: I still find it odd that this is the easiest way to do this fairly common operation in python. In R it would just be grep('berry$', berry_idx). Is there no module that implements a cleaner way to search and get integer locations?

Answer (score 3):

with a function :

```
import re
fruit_list = ['raspberry', 'apple', 'strawberry']
def grep(yourlist, yourstring):
    ide = [i for i, item in enumerate(yourlist) if re.search(yourstring, item)]
    return ide

grep(fruit_list, "berry$")
```