# Python: Use list.index with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, list, search, indexing

I have lists of strings of which i want to extract a certain value:

```
["bla","blabla","blablabla","time taken to build model: 5.1 seconds", "blabla"]
```

Normally I would look for the index of the element I am looking for by

```
list.index("time taken")
```

But since the time changes, I think of using a regular expression. I just can't figure out how to do this.

So how can I find out the index of a list element that matches a certain regex like e.g. re.match()?
(Without iterating through the list, this would take to long)

Comment: Do you really think you can get away without iteration? Even list.index is an iteration. If you need that much performance, use a dictionary with known keys, rather than searching through a list.

Comment: Are there multiple items in the list that have 'time taken' in them?  If so, are you trying to find a specific item based on the *time*.  Do you need to preserve the index of the item in the list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: get list indexes using regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146009/python-get-list-indexes-using-regular-expression)

Comment: Ok lets say it would be preferable if the operation didn't take minutes but if there is no other way I can also iterate. But the idea with a dictionary is good. I am not that deep in python to know that list.index is also iterating. Actually I asked the question, to learn for future tasks and to learn elegant coding.

Comment: @evuez - In principle you are right. It is a duplicate, if there is no other way to do this without iterating. Sorry for that then, I did not find it when searching for an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the info. So since this seemed to be asked before and if no other suggestion will appear, I will delete my question.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if there is a built in method but its easy to do this with list comprehensions in `O(n)` time.

With regular expressions:

```
import re
your_list = ["bla","blabla","blablabla","time taken to build model: 5.1 seconds", "blabla"]
regex = re.compile("^time taken")
idxs = [i for i, item in enumerate(your_list) if re.search(regex, item)]
```

And without regular expressions:

```
your_list = ["bla","blabla","blablabla","time taken to build model: 5.1 seconds", "blabla"]
query_term = 'time taken'
idxs = [i for i, item in enumerate(your_list) if item.startswith(query_term)]
```

You can make it return the first found index or last found index depending or parameterise it in a method to provide flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution need iterate through sequence. If you want get strings with some prefix or suffix, you should implement [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) it's the fastest solution of a problem. Also you can implement solution with cycled hashes of different lengths, but in some cases it will be uneffciient.

Answer (score 0):

If your priority is to get first match in the sequence , then only `index()` is useful.
That's how you do it, if you want to use regex in `index()` method

```
lst=["bla","blabla","blablabla","time taken to build model: 5.1 seconds", "blabla"]

lst.index([i for i in lst if re.findall(r'^time taken', i)][0])
```

Answer (score -1):

To find an element in a list, unless you have extra information (such as order of elements), you have to iterate through it.
If you really want to go faster, change the structure, use a database or use another language.

Comment: Thank you for the info. So since this seemed to be asked before and if no other suggestion will appear, I will delete my question.