# Python list select from second dimension where first dimension = condition

Tags: python, list, search

Let's say I have a 2D-list of values

> [[00000.ppm,11],[00001.ppm,40],[00001.ppm,38],[00001.ppm,13],00002.ppm,39],[00003.ppm,4]]

And I need to select every value from second dimension of list from list where file = "anything.ppm'

> So when I search for 00001.ppm I will get values "40" , "38" , "13" as output

Also I need those values to be separated so I can compare them e.g.

```
_class=13
if (value==_class): do something
```

I was thinking if there is some other way, than just costly looping through whole list, since as a matter of fact - files are in order and their names are always an int increment.

I just don't know how many of each files there is.

Maybe it was a bad idea to read a .csv file into a list for this.

.csv format

```
00000.ppm,11
00001.ppm,40
00001.ppm,38
00001.ppm,13
00002.ppm,39
00003.ppm,4
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to get a list of all values corresponding to particular filenames. Do you have more than 100,000 items in the list of filenames and values? And if so, will you only be searching for a few of the filenames? If the answer to both is yes, then you may want to use the bisect module to search your original list. If the answer to either is no, then your best bet is probably to use a `for` loop to build a dictionary, where the keys are the filenames and the values are a list of matching values. Then you can just read the lists of values  from that dictionary as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking if there is some other way, than just costly looping
>   through whole list, since as a matter of fact - files are in order and
>   their names are always an int increment.

Instead of reading the entire data set to a list and doing a pass through it, you can take advantage of the fact that a file object is iterable, and cease reading from it when you transition from 00001 to 00002.

```
def read_partial(file, key='00001.ppm'):
    with open('obj.csv') as f:
        found = False
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(key):
                yield int(line.split(',')[-1].strip())
                found = True
            else:
                if found:
                    break 



>>> list(read_partial('obj.csv'))
[40, 38, 13]
```

Again, this assumes that the 0000x.ppm field is sorted as in your question.

obj.csv:

```
00000.ppm,11
00001.ppm,40
00001.ppm,38
00001.ppm,13
00002.ppm,39
00003.ppm,4
```

If you do want to take the route of iterating over the list, you could use `[b for a, b in mylist if a == '00001.ppm']`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to get a list of all values corresponding to a particular filename. If you don't have many items and/or you want to check all of the filenames, then your best bet is probably to use a for loop to group all the related values together in a dictionary. But if you have a very long, sorted list of items, and you only want to check a few of the filenames, then you could use the `bisect` module to search the list very quickly.

The code below gives examples of both approaches.

```
entries = [
    ['00000.ppm', 11],
    ['00001.ppm', 40], ['00001.ppm', 38], ['00001.ppm', 13],
    ['00002.ppm', 39],
    ['00003.ppm', 4]
]

# good for most cases:
values = dict()
for filename, value in entries:
    values.setdefault(filename, []).append(value)

print(values['00001.ppm'])
# [40, 38, 13]
# not clear what you want to do with these next...

# this method searches within a sorted list.
# it will be useful if there are many items in the entries list (> ~100000) 
# and you only need to lookup a few
import bisect
def find_values(entries, filename):
    starting_search_key = [filename, -1]
    i = bisect.bisect_left(entries, starting_search_key)
    values = []
    while i < len(entries) and entries[i][0] == filename:
        values.append(entries[i][1])
        i += 1
    return values

print(find_values(entries, '00001.ppm'))
# [40, 38, 13]
```

Alternatively, the Pandas package might be a better all-around option, because it reads csv files very quickly and it can do indexed searches on the resulting data. Here's some code for that:

```
import pandas as pd
entries = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', index_col=0, names=['filename', 'class'])
print(list(entries.loc['00001.ppm', 'class']))
```

If you have a gigantic csv file and only need to do a few searches, you could use the bisection algorithm to search very quickly without reading in much of the file. But you'd probably have to implement the algorithm yourself rather than using the bisect module. You'd have to open the file, then use `file.seek()` to jump to the middle, then scan forward till you reach a carriage return, then check whether the next filename is less than the one you're seeking. If so, jump halfway forward; if not, jump halfway back. Repeat till you find the filename you're interested in. But this has complex edge cases and I wouldn't pursue it unless you have a very large csv file and need to do just a few searches on it. Better alternatives would be to use a database and/or the Dask package.

Comment: Just to add some clarity - the .csv file contains files with their correspodning classes, so I'm trying to compare my results of found classes in the files with the real results - to calculate the precision of my algorithm

Comment: Oh, and the CSV file has 1200 entries, so bisect is not necessary in this case, but I still think it's a good idea to keep this as an example :)

Comment: I think I understand that the csv file contains a long list of (filename, class) pairs. But I'm not sure what you're trying to do with those. Are you creating your own list of (filename, class) pairs by some other method, and then you want to check whether your list matches the list from the csv file (possibly just for a subset of filenames)?

Comment: I'm developing a traffic sign recognition algorithm - the csv file contains TS that are found in the image. I'm simply comparing my results with what is in the csv.

Comment: Can the same TS appear more than once in the same file? If not, then you may want to use the same code as above, but with sets instead of lists. Then you can compare your set to the set read from the csv, using simple equality or difference operators.

Comment: OK, then you'll probably need to sort the list of classes returned for each filename, then compare that list to the sorted list of classes from your own algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to do this without looping through the array.

You can use an approach as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146052/3562088). Here

```
[ i for i, word in enumerate(my_list[:][0]) if word == 'something.ppm' ]
```

should give you the indexes of the elements in the array. Then you can just get the corresponding values in the second column using those indexes:

```
my_list[i][1]
```